# Angular invoke controller fn from directive isolated template

Tags: angularjs, angular-directive

I want `on-click` event from directive invoke some function from my controller. But for some reason it doesn't work. I want my datepicker to expand when I event is fired. Could you please help me to investigate what is wrong my in my current build?

app.js

```
app.directive('myDatepicker', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope :{
            model:'=model',
            minDate:'=minDate',
            isOpened:'=isOpened',
            openFunction: '&'
        },
        templateUrl: 'templates/datepicker/datepicker.html',
        link: function(scope, elm, attrs) {
        }
    };
});

app.controller('FlightDatePickerController', function ($scope) {

    $scope.openFunction = function($event, isDepart) {
        $event.preventDefault();
        $event.stopPropagation();

        $scope.departureOpened = true;
    }; 
};
```

datepicker.html

```
<fieldset>
    <pre>{{model}}</pre>

    <div class='input-group'>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" datepicker-popup ng-model="{{model}}" min-date="{{minDate}}" is-open="{{isOpened}}" datepicker-options="dateOptions" ng-required="true" close-text="Close" />
            <span ng-click='openFunction({event:event}, {isDepart:isDepart})' class="btn btn-default input-group-addon">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
            </span>
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

index.html

```
<div ng-controller="FlightDatePickerController">
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <my-datepicker model="departureDate" minDate="minDateDeparture" isOpened="departureOpened" open-function="openFunction($event, isDepart)"></my-datepicker>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a controller attribute to your directive, in order to bind some function to your template.

In your case, you can do :

**Directive**

```
app.directive('myDatepicker', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope :{
            model:'=model',
            minDate:'=minDate',
            isOpened:'=isOpened'
        },
        templateUrl: 'templates/datepicker/datepicker.html',
        controller: 'FlightDatePickerController'
    };
});
```

**Datepicker.html**

```
  <div ng-controller="FlightDatePickerController">
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <my-datepicker model="departureDate" minDate="minDateDeparture" isOpened="departureOpened"></my-datepicker>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Paul. I've added controller attribute but it didn't help. What could be potential reason? Could you please prepare solution in jsFiddler or plunker?

Answer (score 1):

Your overall implementation is correct, but you made couple of mistakes.

`ng-click` should be like adding parameter in JSON like structure.

```
ng-click='openFunction({event:$event, isDepart:isDepart})'
```

& then your directive element should have

```
open-function="openFunction($event, isDepart)"
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. Unfortunately doesn't work. Even if I create a test function without any params it doesn't fire an event. :(